# Is there any way to better visualise typescript errors?

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I am using [babel typescript preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) to transpile my code. Some TS errors that I am getting emitted in the console could use some better formatting. I wonder if there is some plugin or error parser that would better highlight the nested structures. Changes that I would find useful:

- syntax highlight the types in the emitted errors
- truncate the deep structures to something like breadcrumbs
- if there exists some reference of all error codes and their fixes it would be great to add a link at the top

Answer (score 2):

I was recently looking for something similar. A VSCode extension would be perfect, but unfortunately I don't think it exists yet.

This is the only thing I could find, but I think it's either been shelved or is still in development: https://twitter.com/orta/status/1434904994109612033?s=21

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but now there's the "Typescript error translator" VS Code extension you can use.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattpocock.ts-error-translator

Comment: This vscode extension is now called 'Total Typescript'. It also includes helpful notes for beginners and compliments Matt pockocks excellent TS course of the same name.